# AWS download file from S3 bucket to Windows local directory using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to download a file from S3 bucket to a local directory on my Windows PC using a Lambda function.

I have tried this code named "myLambdaFunction":

```
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    ACCESS_KEY = 'AAA...'
    SECRET_KEY = 'BBB...'

path = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "username", "Downloads")
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY , aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3.download_file('bucketName','1.mat',path)

# TODO implement
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

When I run the following command from the Windows PC:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name myLambdaFunction response.json
```

I get the following error message:

```
{"errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'C:'", "errorType": "OSError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 37, in lambda_handler\n    os.makedirs(path)\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py\", line 221, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\n"]}
```

And when I remove from the code the path check, I get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/username/Downloads.dce48B09'", "errorType": "FileNotFoundError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 39, in lambda_handler\n    s3.download_file('bucketName','1.mat',path)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py\", line 170, in download_file\n    return transfer.download_file(\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py\", line 307, in download_file\n    future.result()\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 106, in result\n    return self._coordinator.result()\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 265, in result\n    raise self._exception\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py\", line 126, in __call__\n    return self._execute_main(kwargs)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py\", line 150, in _execute_main\n    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/download.py\", line 573, in _main\n    fileobj.seek(offset)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py\", line 361, in seek\n    self._open_if_needed()\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py\", line 344, in _open_if_needed\n    self._fileobj = self._open_function(self._filename, self._mode)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py\", line 259, in open\n    return open(filename, mode)\n"]}
```

Somehow the path got concatenated with `.dce48B09`, which I don't understand why.

I know I can use the command

```
aws s3 cp ...
```

in order to copy files, though I need to add more logic and it will be more convenient doing it using Lambda.

Answer (score 3):

The Lambda function isn't running on your local computer. When you run `aws lambda invoke` you are triggering AWS to run an instance of your Lambda function on an AWS server somewhere. The lambda function is not going to have access to your local computer.

If you want to run some Python code on your local computer to download a file from S3, you need to write it as a regular Python script, not a Lambda function.